# Why is my CNN program not improving in accuracy after I add a dropout?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, dropout

I am using a CNN to identify images in the CiFar10 data set and before adding a dropout, the cnn was hitting 58% accuracy, but after adding it, it went down to 52%. Is it the case that the network isn't overfitting? cause I doubt that's the case. After adding two more dropouts, the accuracy went up to 55%, but I'm still confused as to why it dipped in the first place. Here's my code:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 12, 3, padding=1)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(12, 24, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(24, 48, 3, padding=1)
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(48, 48, 3, padding=1)
    self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(48 * 2 * 2, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)


def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(self.dropout1(F.relu(self.conv1(x))))
    x = self.pool(self.dropout2(F.relu(self.conv2(x))))
    x = self.pool(self.dropout3(F.relu(self.conv3(x))))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 48 * 2 * 2)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

Comment: Try plotting the loss to check if there's overfitting as dropout only helps if there is overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be careful about comparing runs if you're training and initializing from scratch. Random weight initialization can sometimes produce the variation you're seeing, especially if other hyperparameters (e.g. learning rate, batch size, etc.) are not yet optimized. Even then, the batch shuffles can cause variation. You ought to set a random seed and/or save weight parameters as you debug all this.

Comment: How could I set the weights to not be random when they're initialized? sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to PyTorch as you can tell.

Comment: Not a dumb question, I may not have been clear. You definitely want/need random weights, but for debugging run-to-run you want those random weights to be repeatable. Some random things you may just want to tone down, e.g. maybe let shuffles be random across runs but keep weights the same (in this case, you can save your model immediately after initialization). Since you're using Pytorch, here's a good article that addresses repeatable results.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html